# How force update data in ListView from Adapter?

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, android-listview

I have custom Adapter for ListView in there i have thread that download bitmap. It work bad, becose when bitmap loaded it not showing in listview, if i wanna see it i must scroll list.

So the question is how do force regenerate view. And in that realization alot of stucks. Is that possible to change?

There is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place> {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private List<Place> mList;


    public Adapter(Activity context, List<Place> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, objects);
        mActivity = context;
        mList = objects;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextViewName;
        private TextView mTextViewAddress;
        private TextView mTextViewWeb;
        private ImageView mImageButtonPhoto;
    }
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mTextViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.mTextViewAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            viewHolder.mTextViewWeb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            viewHolder.mImageButtonPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.mTextViewName.setText(mList.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.mTextViewAddress.setText(mList.get(position).getAddress());
        viewHolder.mTextViewWeb.setText(mList.get(position).getUrl().toString());
        viewHolder.mTextViewWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(mList.get(position).getUrl().toString()));
                mActivity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        URL url = mList.get(position).getPhoto_url();
        final URL finalUrl = url;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Bitmap b;
                try {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(finalUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    viewHolder.mImageButtonPhoto.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            viewHolder.mImageButtonPhoto.setImageBitmap(b);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter after you give it the data?

It will call `invalidate()` on each item's `View`, which makes them redraw.

Edit: Never mind, you need to use the `add(item)` method.

When you're ready to update the data, do a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.getCount(); i++) {
    adapter.add(mList.getItem(i));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if i call it in getView it broke, all. If i call it from activity where is i use adapter it do nothing.

Comment: Ah, I see. You should be using your adapter's `add(Collection<>)` method, which it inherits from `ArrayAdapter`. You don't need to override it. Use that from the Activity, rather than directly changing the drawable, because that can cause problems, possibly the one you're having now. Updated my answer.

Comment: I can't use local drawable only i possible thing it must download.

Comment: Right, put the `for` loop at the end of your download operation, and use your newly downloaded Drawables in the `add()`. If that's giving you issues, consider switching to an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what do you mean. It is already adapter, he didn't collech himself

Comment: @Andrew you have to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you want to update your listview.

Comment: Yes, you should be using an async task to do this.  What Steve is saying, it that when your download finishes, you should add your downloaded content with the adapter.add() function. When you are done adding all of your elements.. just call notifyDataSetChanged() and you are done.